# Lock cells in excel without disabling any other functions

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want to lock a cell or a row/column in excel and all other excel functions should be  work. Normally when I protect a cell in excel with userinterfaceonly, I can expand and collapse group function but I make any other groups. Is there any way to protect spesific cells and do not disabling anything else.

Comment: Please add details in the form of screenshots & code snippets of desired behaviour and what you have tried so far.

Comment: "...I can expand and collapse group function but I make any other group..." do you mean: "...I can expand and collapse group function but ***cannot*** make any other group..."

Comment: If you are using higher version than 2007,, has facility to protect part of Sheet (Range of Sheet) instead of entire,,!